# The problem with displaying the Cyrillic alphabet

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

I’m writing a website. I do this without the help of any CMS, only naked HTML 5 and CSS 3. I wrote a web feedback form. A person enters their name, and when you click “Send”, the mail client opens, where the name is printed in incomprehensible characters. How can I fix this?

The code in the page header is as follows: `<meta charset= "UTF-8">`

I tried changing the encoding, but it didn’t help. I configured Apache by default to UTF-8. The result, too, is zero.

Comment: You forgot to paste the code...

Comment: Make sure you `urlencode` those strings when you put together the mailto URL

Comment: @JS_88 I'd recommend including as many details about your tools/env/apps as possible. For example, which mail client are you using? Where does your HTML form action point? Can you provide a snippet of the mail handling code?

Comment: <form action="mailto:order@kioto.ru" 
    method="post" enctype="text/plain" accept-charset="windows-1251">
    <p><label for="name">Как к Вам обращаться?</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="Имя" id="name" required></p>
    <p><label for="phone">По какому телефону Вам перезвонить?</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="Телефон" id="phone"required></p>
    <p><label for="time">На какое время Вы желаете заказать столик?</label><br>
    <input type="text" name="Время" id="time"required></p>
    <p><input type="submit"></p>
    </form>

Comment: @PeteKarlII  I,m use I the "Windows live Mail" client".  I wrote the code snippet in the previous comment.